# Есть более короткий способ получить response?

Tags: java

По сути стандартный request:

```
URL urla = new URL("http://u.rl/url");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) urla.openConnection();
conn.connect();
////////
conn.disconnect();
```

Здесь всё ок. А вот так происходит получение response:

```
String result = null;
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String frame;

while ((frame=in.readLine())!=null) {

     result+=frame;

}

in.close();
```

Как по мне так длинновато. А можно как-нибудь сразу получить response, не читая построчно?

Comment: Использовать метод read вместо readLine. Только буфер д.б. достаточной длины.

        int  read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)
          Reads characters into a portion of an array.

Comment: @alexlz  int read() 
          Reads a single character.

Comment: @danpetruk http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

       int  read()
          Reads a single character.
       int  read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)
          Reads characters into a portion of an array.